# How can I get the current weekday in Rust using the Chrono crate?

Tags: date, rust, rust-chrono

I am trying to get the current weekday in Rust using the Chrono crate.

The JavaScript equivalent would be something like this:

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US',{weekday: 'long'});
```

I am getting the current timestamp with the following code:

```rust
let current_time = chrono::offset::Local::now();
```

I tried to call a `.weekday()` method on the resulting `DateTime` struct unsuccessfully. I see the `DateLike` trait offers something of that nature in the documentation, but I find myself unable to parse the documentation and produce the corresponding code without an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DateLike` trait, which is implemented by `DateTime` contains a common set of methods for date components, including `weekday`. You can get a `DateTime` from a `Local` offset with the `date` method:

```rust
use chrono::Datelike;

let current_time = chrono::offset::Local::now();
println!("{}", current_time.date().weekday());
```

Comment: Perfect. I see in the [docs](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/enum.Weekday.html) full weekday names are listed as *Variants*. Is there a built in way to pull the full name of the weekday, or I just build my own enum?