# How to get the year, month, and date component from Chrono::DateTime?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

[The documentation](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html) doesn't say anything about this topic. Do I need to convert it into `Date<Tz>`? Even then, there is no function to get the year component from it.

```
let current_date = chrono::Utc::now();
let year = current_date.year();  //this is not working, it should output the current year with i32/usize type
let month = current_date.month();
let date = current_date.date();
```

```
no method named `month` found for struct `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>` in the current scope
```

Comment: Also, the docs [have search functionality](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html?search=year), FWIW.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need the [`DateLike`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.26/chrono/trait.Datelike.html) trait and use its [methods](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.26/chrono/trait.Datelike.html#tymethod.year). Retrieve the `Date` component to operate with it:

```rust
use chrono::Datelike;

fn main() {
    let current_date = chrono::Utc::now();
    println!("{}", current_date.year());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d97984728ffdec11e0e3a2cd142d956)

This trait is available in [`chrono::prelude`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/prelude/index.html), so you can instead `use chrono::prelude::*;`.

Comment: See also [How can I get the current weekday in Rust using the Chrono crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66181608/155423)